# https on TYPO3 - show via pagetree

Tags: https, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a TYPO3 site now running under https. All works fine, except for clicking on Show on a page in the Page tree. I then get an invalid URL which starts like 'https://https//www.'

Steps I did:

- Domain record bla.com 301 redirect to https://www.bla.com
- Domain record https://www.bla.com
- Force SSL backend via $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['lockSSL'] = 2;

Should I set something else to have correct 'Show' links from the pagetree?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tsconfig TCAdefaults.pages.url_scheme = 2 needs to be added (I already had that, but thank you Paul). But a domain record was wrong; the 2nd one needed to be entered without https://

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the backend over SSL too? Died you try to set the url schema inside each page settings from http:// to https:// to exclude this as the error?